# how to let users of an app in mapview drop multiple pins?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dictionary, mkmapview

How do i code a map view in which users can drop multiple pins, make annotations and add pictures?

i know how to code a map view in Xcode and how to put a pre-set pin however i want to be able to code something a bit more complex as it works in relation to an app i'm hoping to create!

1: how do i let a user of the app drop multiple pins to specify a certain location?

2: once the user has dropped a pin i want that he is able to add annotations and pictures?

i have loked extensively into this and although i have found how to code basic maps into an app i have not been able to code the follow up parts!

thank you for reading my question and would really appreciate any suggestions that can be given. if you think there is a useful youtube video or a blog that you think could help me please put it at the bottom and i will look through it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make an Annotation class that implements the `<MKAnnotation>` protocol:

```
@interface Annotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *otherInfo;
    UIImage *image;
    // etc...any other info you want to include with your annotation
}
```

Then when you want to drop a pin:

```
-(void)dropPin:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)location (NSString *)title (NSString *)subtitle (NSString *)otherInfo (UIImage *)image
{
    Annotation *pin = [Annotation annotationWithCoordinate:location];
    pin.title = title;
    pin.subtitle = subtitle;
    pin.otherInfo = otherInfo;
    pin.image = image;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];
}
```

You'll probably also want to store your dropped pins in an array or something so you can keep track of them and reference them later.

Take a look at the  [MapKit documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) for the `MKAnnotation` protocol for more information and examples.  Also read [this tutorial](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-beginners/), which gives an excellent overview of how to use the MapKit objects and protocols, including annotations.

Comment: thank you! hwo would i set up an array to store the dropped pins?

Comment: Create an NSMutableArray somewhere - probably an instance variable in your map view controller.  Then in the dropPin method above, just do: `[pinArray addObject:pin];`